# Concatenate attribute selector with variable does a syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works, the class is added, but I am receiving an error.

```
console.log(key);    //first_date
$('*[name='+key+']').addClass('error');
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `*[name=]`
```

What is wrong here?

```
<input id="date-picker-1" type="text" class="date-picker form-control hasDatepicker" name="first_date">
```

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: Wheres the key coming from?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar updated with html.

Comment: looks like `key` is blank - try `$('*[name="'+key+'"]').addClass('error');`

Comment: Show more js code. This code gives back no error for me.

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, It solves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is happening because your `key` variable is empty. `'*[name='+key+']'` is evaluating to `'*[name=]'`. To avoid the error, you can wrap your `key` variable in quotes:

```
$('*[name="'+key+'"]').addClass('error');
```

This way you will not get the error as instead of trying to evaluate `*[name=]` it will try to evaluate `*[name=""]`. However as your `key` variable appears to be empty, this will probably not produce the result you're looking for.

Double check your code to ensure `key` is set prior to `addClass` being called.

---

In fact, if what you say is true that the "error" class is added, I imagine your code here is being executed twice - once when `key` is empty, and again when `key` is in fact equal to "first_date".